AudioTrack is disabled due to previous underrun error on releaseBuffer()
I'm developing an Android app that uses AudioTrack for audio playback. I have encountered an issue where the AudioTrack gets disabled due to a previous underrun error when calling releaseBuffer().

releaseBuffer() track 0x79a3234000 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting

This happens on some phones but not on others. For example, on a Xiaomi phone, the audio is heard clearly and I don't encounter this warning, while on a Samsung phone, I do encounter this warning and the sound is choppy.
Here's the relevant part of my code where I initialize and use the AudioTrack:
private lateinit var audioTrack: AudioTrack
private val bufferSize = 3200
private val sampleRate = 16000
private val channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO
private val audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
    
...

audioTrack = AudioTrack.Builder()
    .setAudioAttributes(
        AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
            .build()
    )
    .setAudioFormat(
        AudioFormat.Builder()
            .setEncoding(audioFormat)
            .setSampleRate(sampleRate)
            .setChannelMask(channelConfig)
            .build()
    )
    .setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize)
    .setTransferMode(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM)
    .setPerformanceMode(AudioTrack.PERFORMANCE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
    .build()

I've adjusted the bufferSize ranging from 300 to 6400, but this warning persists.
